# All my fields are tabindex=-1 in my editview

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

I've created a custom module based on people template.

i've customised the editView (which is synced with the detailView) and I have assigned a tabindex value for every field.

But when I use that editView almost every field has tabindex=-1 so I only can't get to them using my mouse, which is very slow.

I was changing include/EditView/EditView.tpl but it looks the changes there has no effect on the generated code.

I changed all tabindex=$tabindex for a tabindex="-3", "-4", "5" in every tabindex assignment, but I couldn't see it in my html page, I also tried making a QRR previously.

So my question is where can I fix that -1 issue or, at least, where is really being generated my editView.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

Well! I found a workaround... I guessed that the problem was the autogenerated fields, they had no "space" among another fields's tabindex values...

So, instead of giving the fields tabindex values of 1, 2, 3, 4... I gave them as 10, 20, 30, 40...

And, against all odds, it works!

Perhaps it's useful for somebody....

Comment: I was introducing this solutions to another edit views when it stopped working due to unknown reasons, even in the forms previously ok.

Needs more research...

Answer (score 1):

Well, I finally found where this fields, and tabindex values of course, were generated.

The include/EditView/EditView.tpl has been overwritten by the themes/suiteP/include/EditView/EditView.tpl.

This SmartyTemplate calls tab_panel_content.tpl in the same folder... Well, as I'm using SuitePImproved this wasn't true, suitePImproved/include/EditView/EditView.tpl was loading suiteP/include/EditView/tab_panel_content.tpl so that had to be fixed.

Anyway, in the tab_panel_content.tpl file you find tabindex=$tabindex 4 times, that $tabindexare replaced by:

1. $subfields.tabindex
2. $colData.field.tabindex
3. $colData.field.tabindex
4. $colData.field.tabindex

And this is working everywhere for me.

This change is not upgrade-safe because I didn't get loaded that tpl from the custom/themes... I'll come back later to fix that